# how do I feed an rtf string to a richtextbox control

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a string of richtext characters/tokens that I would like to feed to a richtextbox in code.

```
string rt  = @" {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0     Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 Biondi;}}"+
@"{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}"+
@"{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\par"+
@"\cf1\f1 hello\cf0\f0  \ul world\par}";
```

I have attempted this :

```
      System.IO.MemoryStream strm = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
      byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rt);
      strm.BeginRead(b, 0, b.Length, null, null);

      richTextBox1.LoadFile(strm, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

it didn't work.

can anyone give me a few sugestions.

BTW the rich text comes from saving from wordpad, opening the file with notepad and using the text with in to build my string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rich textbox has a property named Rtf.  Set that property to your string value.  Also, your string has an extra space as the first character.  I had to remove that before I saw your Hello World.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on gbogumil's answer:

```
string rt  = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0     Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 Biondi;}}"+
@"{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}"+
@"{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\par"+
@"\cf1\f1 hello\cf0\f0  \ul world\par}";

this.richTextBox1.Rtf = rt;
```