# C# RichTextBox Not Displaying Drawn Lines From .rtf

Tags: c#, line, richtextbox, rtf

I have a rich text file that has a line drawn as such.

```
{\rtf1
{\pard some text.\par}
{\pard {\*\do\dobxcolumn\dobypara\dodhgt\dpline\dpxsize9200\dplinesolid\dplinew20}}
{\pard some other text.\par}
}
```

When I open this file in MS Word the line displays properly.  When I open the file in Open office or WordPad it does not show the line.  Also, when I load the file in a RichTextBox it does not show either.

Does anyone know if a C# RichTextBox can display a line drawn in an .rtf?

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I feed an rtf string to a richtextbox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601917/how-do-i-feed-an-rtf-string-to-a-richtextbox-control)

Comment: My question is different. I can diplay the .rtf in a C# RichTextBox it's just that when displayed it does not show the line that is coded in the file.

Comment: Rephrasing the question a bit ... can a RichTextBox in a C# program display lines, eclipses and graphics?

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657918/5552166) answer, also read the comments below the answer, hope it provides some info.